# Создание html элемента в DOM средствами Javascript

Tags: javascript

Доброе время суток, подскажите пожалуйста как этот код написать на VanillaJs
Знаю о существовании `<div>Текст</div>` , но по итогу получается текст, а не html...

```
$('#modal-login, .modal-backdrop').remove();

html  = '<div id="modal-login" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">';
html += '  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-fullscreen-sm-down modal-md">';
html += '    <div class="modal-content">';
html += '    </div>';
html += '  </div>';
html += '</div>';

$('body').append(html);

$('#modal-login').modal('show');
```

Comment: Приведите код, где вы пытаетесь сделать это без jquery и у вас текст вместо html.

Comment: const newModal = `<div id="modal-login" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-fullscreen-sm-down modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>`

    document.body.append(newModal);
    
    $('#modal-login').modal('show');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь создаётся дополнительный div, чтобы избежать этого, надо использовать добавления [классов](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes#classname-i-classlist) и [атрибутов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) создаваемому элементу.

```js
const div = document.createElement('div')

const newModal = `
<div id="modal-login" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-fullscreen-sm-down modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Тест
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
div.innerHTML = newModal
document.body.append(div);
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое, а через <template></template> как можно эту задачу решить не подскажите ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template попробуйте и пишите, если будет что-то конкретное не получаться